# How to parse an xml file to get the fields?

Tags: c#, xml, format

I have an xml file and I need to parse it to get the information-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <feed xml:base="http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.giooglt.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Partners</title>
  <id>http://googlre.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners</id>
  <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
  < link rel="self" title="Partners" href="Partners" />
<entry>
   <id>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4555')</id>
   <title type="text">M55p; Co</title>
   <summary type="text">cccc is a Certified Partner, reseller, and implementer of 
 Key industries we work with include:
•   Financial services
•   Professional services
•   Media / publishing


 By focusing on mid-market to enterprise clients, 
</summary>
 <published>2009-07-21T14:23:50-07:00</published>
 <updated>2013-11-22T15:00:46-08:00</updated>
 <author>
   <name>google chrome</name>
  <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
  <email>retee@gmail.com</email>
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('4255')" />
<link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Links" href="Partners('4559')/Links">
  <m:inline>
    <feed>
      <title type="text">Links</title>
      <id>http://google.com/('429')/Links</id>
      <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
      <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('4ff')/Links" />
      <entry>
        <id>http://ryryr.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('ufufr')</id>
        <title type="text">
        </title>
        <updated>2014-01-16T21:33:20Z</updated>
        <author>
          <name />
        </author>
        <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
        <category term="google.Commerce.ferrr.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link" scheme="http://schemas.frrr.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <content type="application/xml">
          <m:properties>
            <d:Type>pgooglrpartnerpage</d:Type>
            <d:Description>google Partner Page</d:Description>
            <d:Url>http://googlgt.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=42555&amp;wt.mc_id=66ttet</d:Url>
          </m:properties>
        </content>
      </entry>
      </m:inline>
      </entry>
```

I am using the piece of code to generate the information -

```
    // Alternate Method for getting the Fields from the XML file
         XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
         xmlDocument.Load("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");
        XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
        xmlnm.AddNamespace("de","http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

        ParseXML(xmlDocument, xmlnm);

        Debug.WriteLine("\n---XML parsed---");

    }

    public static void ParseXML(XmlDocument xmlFile, XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm)
    {
        //XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//ns:entry/ns:updated| //ns:entry/ns:published | //ns:entry/ns:id ", xmlnm);
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//de:entry/de:link/de:inline/de:feed/de:id ", xmlnm);

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(node.Name + " = " + node.InnerXml);
        }
```

In the above program I want to get the information as "//de:entry/de:link/de:m:inline/de:feed/de:id"  i.e trying to extract the information under  but the program does not recognize "/de:m:inline" as the right format and generating an error stating "incorrect format"  , I wish to parse the information to get the data as specified but do not know how to generate the  right format. New to C# please help me with the following.

Sample of the code that fails:

```
xmlFile.SelectNodes("//de:link/de:m:inline", xmlnm);
```

Error:

> '//de:m:inline' has an invalid token

Comment: Please post line, stack and exact error message when exception happens.

Comment: '//de:entry/de:link/de:m:inline/de:feed/de:id ' has an invalid token.

Comment: @user3199528 you should be responsive if u are asking questions.

Comment: @user3199528 - for future questions please post code that *does not work* or shows *error case*. Your code in sample looked fine and it was very puzzling why it did not produce result you wanted. Usually people pay more attention to values code than in the text because it is not possible to compile text to make sure there is no errors. I.e. in your case on line sample `new XmlDocument().SelectNodes("//a:b:c")` would clearly show the issue and it would no time to find the solution (+1 to PawanS for reading post very carefully)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was able help him because I faced similar issue and yeah it was really difficult to understand this messy question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : sorry for the mess but actually have re-posted the question as - "How to get the each values in Ienumerable<String> Urls' in c# for a multiple value xml file?" with complete Xml file and reference code and also the problem I am facing right now. Thanks for  the consideration and any help is appreciated.

Comment: @PawanS: please to the post "How to get the each values in Ienumerable<String> Urls' in c# for a multiple value xml file?" for complete clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both namespaces `de` and `m`

```
public static void Main()
    {
        // Alternate Method for getting the Fields from the XML file
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");
        XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);

        xmlnm.AddNamespace("de", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"); 

        **** add this too****
        xmlnm.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.giooglt.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");

        ParseXML(xmlDocument, xmlnm);

        Console.WriteLine("\n---XML parsed---");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }



 public static void ParseXML(XmlDocument xmlFile, XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm)
    {
       /// inline should be ""m"" not ""de""
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//de:entry/de:link/m:inline/de:feed/de:id", xmlnm);
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Name + " = " + node.InnerXml);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. As a first time C#  user things like these are pretty tricky.

Answer (score 0):

To get your information from a XML file you can use XDocument to pass your data to it then iterating on each element (node) that's exist in your file and get it's inner nodes or attributes or etc.
Like this :
string PdFileContent = string.Empty;

```
            string FileContent = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(**FilePath**, UTF8Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                FileContent = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            XmlDocument XDoc = new XmlDocument();

            XDoc.LoadXml(FileContent); //Load the file with XML strcuture

            XDoc.SelectNodes("/**NodeNameToSelect**");

            // Read inner text of the XDocument's Child Elements
            string Result = XDoc["**ChildNodeName**"].InnerText;
```